# Sending an email via localhost in PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp

I'm trying to send an email through PHP. It gives the following warning.

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at 
"smtp.ntlworld.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in 
php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\wagafashion\customerside\BulkInquiry.php 
on line 1007
```

In php.ini, [SMTP](http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtpservers.html) has been changed as follows.

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = smtp.ntlworld.com
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from = tiny1999@gmail.com
```

After configuring php.ini, WAMP was restarted and it gave the above warning. What other settings are to be made to send an email via localhost in PHP?

Comment: *Other* settings? Fix the settings you *already have*...

Comment: Can you connect to that server on port 25 from the command line? Do you need to add in a username and password?

Comment: Changing SMTP to `smtp.gmail.com` and port to `587` gives this warning `Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ru4sm13726850pbc.66 in C:\wamp\www\wagafashion\customerside\BulkInquiry.php on line 1007`.

Comment: @Tiny did you check the configuration of your firewall ? AV security software ? and maybe the router you're behind ?

Answer (score 1):

Use PHPMailer instead: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

How to use it:

```
require('./PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail=new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$body = 'This is the message';

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;

$mail->Username   = 'me.sender@gmail.com';
$mail->Password   = '123!@#';

$mail->SetFrom('me.sender@gmail.com', $name);
$mail->AddReplyTo('no-reply@mycomp.com','no-reply');
$mail->Subject    = 'subject';
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAddress('abc1@gmail.com', 'title1');
$mail->AddAddress('abc2@gmail.com', 'title2'); /* ... */

$mail->AddAttachment($fileName);
$mail->send();
```